# Use one Message as argument in other Spring Messages (properties file)

Tags: spring, resources, properties, message

I have a need to do something like this:

```
bob.common=goat
bob.have=I have a {bob.common}!
bob.want=I want a {bob.common}!
bob.need=I need a {bob.common}!
```

Is this sort of thing possible? I know this seems silly, but being able to re-use a common piece is a need here, and we really can't (don't want to) do it programmatically.

We're already using numbered arguments in our properties, but we would like to be able to pass in a reference to another property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Spring changelog](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/changelog.txt), this has been supported since 2.5.3:

- PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer supports nested keys in placeholder keys as well (e.g. "${db.${environment}}")

So for your example case, you should be able to use:

```
bob.have=I have a ${bob.common}!
```

and the [PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html) should recognise the "nested key" and resolve that correctly.

Comment: Interesting. I'll give that a shot tomorrow!

Comment: FWIW, this is not working for me in an actual *Messages* file. I thought it was too good to be true. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5):

I suggest to do this :

```
bob.common=goat 
bob.have=I have a {0}!
bob.want=I want a {0}!
bob.need=I need a {0}!
```

Then in your page :

```
<spring:message code="bob.common" var="animal"/>
<spring:message code="bob.have" arguments="${animal}"/>
<spring:message code="bob.want" arguments="${animal}"/>
<spring:message code="bob.need" arguments="${animal}"/>
```

The way you want to do would be too strict, if you want to change your animal for example.